# What does positive co-dimension mean in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, measure-theory

I'm just trying to understand a line in a specific proof but I'm a little unfamiliar with some of the terminology. The proof in question is Lemma 5 on Page 3 of [Piecewise Contractions are Asymptotically Periodic](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-04/S0002-9939-08-09633-0/S0002-9939-08-09633-0.pdf), but I'll paraphrase for convenience.

The result is in regards to the dynamics of a piecewise contraction on a disc in the plane $\mathbb{C}$ (that is, the disc is partitioned into finitely many $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^K$ such that for each $k$, $G|_{X_k}$ is an affine map contracting distances). Thus the piecewise continuous map is:

$$
G(z):=G_k(z)=\lambda_k z + (1-\lambda_k)w_k:\text{       $z \in X_k$}
$$

For $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_K)\in \mathbb{D}^K$ ($\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc) and $w = (w_1, \ldots,w_K)\in \mathbb{C}^K$. Define $S$ as the union of the boundaries $\partial X_k$ of each of the segments.

At one point in a proof by contradiction, the author shows that there is some $x \in S$ such that $G^{(r_i)}(x) \in S$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$ and $r_i \in \mathbb{N}$. That is, there is a point in the boundaries that maps to another point in the boundaries at least twice. (Page 3, last line).

It is then argued that this is a contradiction by stating:

> This is a condition that happens with positive co-dimension, so for Lebesgue
>   a.e. $w$, it will not occur.

I'm assuming this is stating something to the effect of: since the boundaries are one-dimensional slice in a two-dimensional plane, there is no finite sequence of affine functions that can map the boundary set to itself more than once.

I was hoping someone could elaborate on what the exact argument is, perhaps with a reference to a generalisation to higher dimensions? For context: I am trying to see how to apply the Lemma to a higher dimensional but identical piecewise contraction map in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with a known set of intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a statement about a tuple of points $w=(w_1,...,w_K) \in \mathbb C^K = \mathbb R^{2K}$.

After that, I believe what they are saying is that the set of points $w$ for which this condition occurs is a set of dimension $\le 2K-1$ (or of codimension $\ge 1$, i.e. of positive codimension), and then they are using the fact that the Lebesgue measure of every set of dimension $\le 2K-1$ is equal to zero. The point seems to be that the boundary of region $X_k \subset \mathbb C$ is a rectifiable curve, which has "dimension $1$", and therefore has Lebesgue measure zero; then one is working with the images of the boundaries of the $X_k$ under iterates of the contraction mappings, all of which still have dimension $1$ and therefore Lebesgue measure zero; and one is perhaps taking products of at least one of these boundaries with other stuff to get a region in $\mathbb R^{2K}$, and so the dimension is $\le 2K-1$ and so has Lebesgue measure zero.

It is also possible that they are saying something ever so slightly more complicated, namely that the set for which this condition occurs is a union of countably many sets of dimension $\le 2K-1$, but a union of countably many sets of Lebesgue measure zero has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Thanks very much if I could just ask a couple of clarifying questions. I understand the images of the boundaries have measure zero, but is this a sufficient condition to conclude that the boundary cannot map to itself twice? I also admit I'm struggling to see the relevance of the dimension $K$ to the argument in the proof, as $K$ simply enumerates the number of partitions of the map.

Comment: The statements they are making about Lebesgue measure are statements about $w$, which is a $K$- tuple of points in $\mathbb C$, equivalently a point of $\mathbb C^K$. You may have to read the paper in detail to see why they care about tuples, but that's clearly what's going on with these Lebesgue measure statements.

Comment: I've been through the paper in detail and must admit it's unclear why it's being introduced in the way it has been. Nonetheless, I'm more interested in the result around mapping a set of zero measure to itself (i.e. mapping a point on the boundary to another point on the boundary, twice) - is there anything you can point me to that elaborates on why this is not possible?